# How do you put symbols at the end of every line?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm doing vocabulary for class, and want to add a colon on the end of each line to separate the word and the definition, but there are a lot of words, so I was wondering if there was a way I could do this all at once? I need a quick answer, it's due tomorrow!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Search & Replace](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/FindingSpecialCharacters.htm):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>
- Search for paragraph marks: `^p`.
- Replace them with the punctuation and reinsert the paragraph, e.g. `;^p`.